# Okhttp3 Requestbody create() companion deprecated. Docs confusing

Tags: android, okhttp

I have a glide module borrowed from a github repo. IDE says create() function is deprecated. But to me, okhttp docs seems confusing. Could anyone help changing this one into a valid one.

```
@GlideModule
class AppGlideModule : AppGlideModule()
const val MULTIPART_MEDIA_TYPE = "multipart/form-data"
const val IMAGE_MEDIA_TYPE = "image/*"
fun createRequestBody(s: String, type: String? = MULTIPART_MEDIA_TYPE): RequestBody {
    return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(type), s)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fun createRequestBody(s: String, type: String? = MULTIPART_MEDIA_TYPE): RequestBody {
    return s.toRequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(type))
}
```

Comment: I used this one. `return s.toRequestBody(MediaType.parse(type!!))` the IDE says `'parse(String):Mediatype?'` is an error

Comment: Does the quickfix on that error suggest a replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
val fileName = s.toRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
```

You can use media type based on requirements as I used "multipart/form-data" for mine.